# Import CSV from website to Google Sheets

Tags: csv, import, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The file I want to import into the Google Sheets is from the website http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/newl/historical. Under Select the Timeframe, I want 6 months. The actual CSV file is at the bottom of the page where it says "Download this file in Excel format."

I have tried:

```
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(unescape(encodeURIComponent(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().toString())));
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
sheet.getRange(i + lastRow, 1, 1, data[i].length).setValues(new Array(data[i]));
```

Apparently the url fetches an HTML file, not the CSV I want.

Comment: This won't be so simple ! the page has a script and the csv download is initiated by the script... the result you get with your code is normal, url fetch gets what a browser gets. btw, what about your previous post (array of dates) ?

Comment: Re: my previous post - I finally figured it out! Thanks, Stackoverflow!

Comment: Using my answer or something else?

Comment: I used something else because I ended up with a ton of bugs and had to rewrite the entire thing, piece by piece.

Comment: I just renamed the file to 'txt' instead of 'csv' after downloading and after opening in Notepad I saw NO html tag, just plain text. Data being komma separated.

Comment: How do you import it to Google Sheets without downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

This function wil directly import that table without having to download it:

=IMPORTHTML("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/newl/historical","table",6)